# IRA-00904: "STOREBALANCE": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 49

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to build an oracle query which results the below Report

```
Name    AccountId   DistributorBalance  DealerBalance   StoreBalance
```

I should fetch the data from three linked tables which are:

- partners
- partneraccounts
- accounts

The partners will repeat three times as of self join
and every join of the three self join `partner` should join `partneraccounts` table; also the `accounts` should join `partneraccounts` table. I build this subquery and receiving the following error:

```
Select dis.name,DistributorBalace,DealerBalance,StoreBalance From
(
 select dis.name,disa.credit-disa.debit DistributorBalace 
        from partners dis join
        partneraccounts disp on dis.partnerid=disp.partnerid
        join  accounts disa on disa.accountid=disp.accountid
        where dis.identitytypeid=19
        union all
select de.name, dea.credit-dea.debit DealerBalance from partners de join
        partneraccounts dep on dep.partnerid=de.partnerid
        join  accounts dea on dea.accountid=dep.accountid
        where de.identitytypeid=7
        union all
select ag.name,aga.credit-aga.debit StoreBalance from partners ag join
        partneraccounts apa on apa.partnerid=ag.partnerid
        join  accounts aga on aga.accountid=apa.accountid
        where ag.identitytypeid=8 ) A
```

```
Error
ORA-00904: "STOREBALANCE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 49
```

Comment: try putting `as` keyword `select ag.name,aga.credit-aga.debit as StoreBalance` and put this in all queries.

Comment: i did not get you bro, how to put this on all queries i need different data result on three queries

Comment: since this is union, all the columns from all queries should be of same type. remove DistributorBalace , DealerBalance , StoreBalance  from your queries and then run it

Comment: You have given the subqeury result the name `A`. I.e. you can only select `A.name` etc.

Comment: Same tables in all UNION-ed tables. Can't you simply do one single SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

A UNION query has the projection of the toppermost subquery. In your case that is `name, DistributorBalance` (note correction of the typo). There is no column called `StoreBalance` in that projection, hence the error.

You want all three balances in the output, so you need subqueries which return all three. Note your specified output also wants the `accountid`, so include that as well. Something like this:

```
select a.name
      ,a.accountid
      ,a.DistributorBalance
      ,a.DealerBalance
      ,a.StoreBalance
from (
  select dis.name
        ,disp.accountid
        ,disa.credit - disa.debit as DistributorBalance 
        ,cast(null as number)     as DealerBalance
        ,cast(null as number)     as StoreBalance
  from    partners        dis 
  join    partneraccounts disp on dis.partnerid = disp.partnerid
  join    accounts        disa on disa.accountid = disp.accountid
  where  dis.identitytypeid = 19
  union all
  select  de.name
          dea.accountid
         ,cast(null as number)   as DistributorBalance 
         ,dea.credit - dea.debit as DealerBalance 
         ,cast(null as number)   as StoreBalance
  from   partners        de 
  join   partneraccounts dep on dep.partnerid = de.partnerid
  join   accounts        dea on dea.accountid = dep.accountid
  where de.identitytypeid = 7
  union all
  select  ag.name
         ,aga.accountid
         ,cast(null as number)   as DistributorBalance
         ,cast(null as number)   as DealerBalance
         ,aga.credit - aga.debit as StoreBalance 
  from   partners        ag 
  join   partneraccounts apa on apa.partnerid = ag.partnerid
  join   accounts        aga on aga.accountid = apa.accountid
  where ag.identitytypeid = 8
) a
```

---

To be honest, a union query like this may not be the most efficient way of doing things, depending on the characteristics of the data (volume, distribution, etc). I leave the query as above because it answers the question posed, but if execution time were to prove an issue I would extract the joins on the three tables into a single WITH clause subquery, and replace the UNION subqueries with selects on that. Or just use three CASE statements for the different balances. This refactoring is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Thanks Bro, now the error has gone but as you stated above the result is not answering the required data, bcz distributor table name field should  only be displayed , while the result is giving all three tables

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be much simpler with conditional aggregation:

```
select p.name,
       sum(case when p.identitytypeid = 19 then a.credit - a.debit end) as DistributorBalance,
       sum(case when p.identitytypeid = 7 then a.credit - a.debit end) as DealerBalance,
       sum(case when p.identitytypeid = 8 then a.credit - a.debit end) as StoreBalance
from partners p join
     partneraccounts pa
     on p.partnerid = pa.partnerid join
     accounts a
     on a.accountid = pa.accountid
group by p.name;
```